# Basic pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, limit

I am not a well-versed programmer so i don't want to use a complicated pagination.  Is there an alternative to using a pagination like in my queries can i limit them to say 20 results and then if their are more than 20 results i can show a "next" button and then that button will further load the next results??

I only want "next" to show if there are 20> results?  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Code:

```
  $query="SELECT * FROM actresses where actress_id = '$actressid' and production_full_name LIKE '%$q%'";  
       $result=mysql_query($query);

        $num=mysql_numrows($result);

        mysql_close();

          echo "";

       $i=0;
         while ($i < $num) {

         $1=mysql_result($result,$i,"production_full_name");
           $2=mysql_result($result,$i,"production_id");
     $3=mysql_result($result,$i,"actress");


          echo "<br><div id=linkcontain><a id=slink   href=$data/actress.php?id=$2>$3</a><div id=production>$1</div></div>";

            echo "";

            $i++;
            }
```

Comment: You'll need to show some code, otherwise we have no context as to how to help you.

Comment: @zzzzBov code has been added.

Comment: As a side note, you're reusing an `id` on your `<div>` and `<a>` tags with every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a limit to your query.

```
$lower_limit = $results_per_page * $page_number;
$upper_limit = $lower_limit + $results_per_page

..and production_full_name LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT $lower_limit, $upper_limit
```

Then make a conditional "next page" link

```
if ($upper_limit > 20) echo '<a href="{page url}?page_number='.($page_number+1).'">Next</a>;
```

Comment: I'm not  sure that this will work correct. Your upper limit is wrong. LIMIT with two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. [Source: MySQL page.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4528204) Something like this would be correct: `$lower_limit = ($results_per_page * $page_number) - $results_per_page; $upper_limit = $results_per_page;`

Comment: @tastro I guess it matters if you're starting at page 0 or 1, but you are correct.  If you are assuming page 1 should contain row 1..n, then you have to subtract n from your upper and lower limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can find many examples searching on google.
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx for example.

You only have to edit **$rowsPerPage** for amount of results, and if you want further edit on what to get from the DB, the **$query**.

Includes are not necessary, though.

edit: note the implication of using a $_GET that will have influence on the DB query. You have to be careful to not allow dangerous values in it (**mysql injection**). In the example of the webpage, it uses ceil, so I believe that it will output 0 for a non numeric value, which is safer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PEAR packages.
They are much easier to use similar to the frameworks.
But before you use them you need to check whether the PEAR works on your server or not.
If you are using it locally then there are steps to install the PEAR packages on your local machine. For more instructions to install PEAR.
[Click here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallPearOnWindowsWithWamp) to view the installation steps.

Once you have installed the PEAR package please follow the instruction to configure the PAGER class.http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/

J

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$total_data = mysql_num_rows($data);

$step = 30;
$from = $_GET['p'];

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT '.$from.','.$step.'"
```

And creating links:

```
$p=1;
for ($j = 0 ; $j <= $total_data+$step; $j+=$step) 
{ 
    echo ' <a href="page.php?p='.$j.'">'.$p.'</a> '; 
    $p++;

} ?>
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is fetch a `COUNT(*)` of how many rows are in your set of data. Then decide how many items you want per page. `$numberOfRows / $itemsPerPage` gives you the number of pages. In MySQL, to limit results you use `LIMIT X, Y` X is the beginning of the range, and Y is the number of items you want to fetch. So to fetch all the items on a page, your query would be `LIMIT ($currentPage * $itemsPerPage), $itemsPerPage` Then it's up to you, depending on how you want to format your pagination, to write the view logic. Just go from back to front: if the current page is 1, then the previous button is disabled. If the page is not 1, then the current page number is the number of pages from the beginning. If the total number of pages is bigger than the current page, then count from the current page, until the last page (unless you want to cut off the page count at some point)

I use the following method to assist in creating a list of pages, no matter what direction. I could plug in 5 for the current page, and 0 as the goal page, and it would return a list of 5 pages for me to iterate through, in order.

```
/*
 * Generates a list of pages based on the current page to the goal page number
 */
function generatePageList($currentPage, $goal) {
    $span = $goal - $currentPage;
    $step = abs($span) / $span;
    $list = array();

    for($x = $currentPage; $x !== $goal;) {
        // We want to add the step at the beginning of the loop, instead of 
        // at the end
        // Fixes bug when there are only two pages
        $x += $step;
        $list[] = $x;
    }

    return $list;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query is set up as

```
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM actresses where actress_id = '$actressid' and production_full_name LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT ".($page*$lpage).",".$lpage
```

... the next statement can be [`SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to get the actual number of results.
Don't forget to put `mysql_real_escape_string()` on those variables.

NEVER use `SELECT *` with mysql_num_rows; if it's a big table, it will waste a LOT of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is more easy way to create pagination of a data

```
<?php
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    $limit = 20;  
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
?>


<table class="table table-bordered">  
        <thead>  
            <tr>  
                <th>Name</th>  
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Age</th>  
            </tr>  
        </thead>  
            <tbody>  
                <?php  
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {?>  
                        <tr>  
                            <td><?php echo $row["employee_name"]; ?></td>  
                            <td><?php echo $row["employee_salary"]; ?></td>  
                            <td><?php echo $row["employee_age"]; ?></td>  
                        </tr>  
                        <?php  
                    };  
                ?>  
            </tbody>  
</table>



<?php  
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM employee";  
        $rs_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
        $total_records = $row[0];  
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
        $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";  
        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){  
            $pagLink .= "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
        };  
        echo $pagLink . "</ul></nav>";  
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pagination').pagination({
            items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
            itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage : <?php echo $page;?>,
            hrefTextPrefix : 'index.php?page='
        });
    });
</script>
```